# Sort a list of functions in Python

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list of integers which is dynamically changing
Instead of doing it in the order of the list `actual` I want to sort it so it starts by the lowest number and execute the function associated.

Here is the code I simplified :

```
actual = [500, 175, 12]


def a():
    do_something()

def b():
    do_something()

def c():
    do_something()

def func1():
    while actual[0] <= 1000:
        a()
        break
    return actual[0]


def func2():
    while actual[1] > 150 and actual[1] <= 185:
        b()
        break
    return actual[1]


def func3():
    while actual[2] <= 14:
        c()
        break
    return actual[2]


int_list = []

int_list.append(func1())
int_list.append(func2())
int_list.append(func3())

int_list.sort()

# ?
```

The issue I'm having first is that when I append a function to the `int_list`, it executes it, but I don't want to execute it, first adding the functions to the list, then sort the number associated and finally execute it.

If my code or my question is not clear I can modify it.

thank you for your time :)

Comment: If you want to append function `f` to list `lst`, use `lst.append(f)`, not `lst.append(f())`.  The former appends the function.  The latter calls the function, then appends the result.

Comment: Note that your `while` loops are effectively just `if` statements, since you unconditionally break at the end of the loop bodies.  So instead of `while cond: func(); break`, just do `if cond: func()`.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Why does the function need to be in the list before it is called? Can you explain- `sort the number associated`?

Comment: I changed that, it's partially working, but now when i'm trying to sort it I got the error telling me that '<' is not supported between instances of 'function' and 'function'. Have you got an idea ? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You probably want to use a `dic` so that a given number can be associated with a function. Otherwise how would the program (or anyone for that matter) know which function should go first?

Comment: the list actual is the result of a function that puts the numbers i need in a list. If you're talking about the int_list list, this is the only way I found to sort the numbers and execute the function to the associated number :/

Comment: In oder to help to explain this challenge why not show the expected output for the input data you've shown. You will also need to consider that any value less than or equal to 14 is also less than or equal to 1000. So let's say a value is 10, would you want to execute 2 functions?

Comment: Does `actual` always contain the same number of items as functions? In your example there are three functions - will `actual` always have three items?

Comment: ```actual``` will always have 3 values, the functions axecuted are always different, for a value to another, i'm sorry if the functions are doing the same thing but no, it's always different, it was just to use as example.

Comment: If `actual[0]` is `1001` will func1 be called and nothing will *happen*? Or is func1 called only if `actual[0]` is <= 1000?  Does func1 **only** *care about* `actual[0]`, func1 has NO relation to `actual[1:]`?

Comment: Does the position of the numbers in `actual` have meaning? Is `actual = [500, 175, 12]` the same as `actual = [175, 12, 500]`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you want to call certain functions depending on a range check. Thus the functions are associated with a range rather than the value found in *actual*

If that's the case, you could do this:

```
actual = [500, 175, 12]

def a(v):
    print('a', v)

def b(v):
    print('b', v)

def c(v):
    print('c', v)

# lo and hi values for the range and a reference to the relevant function
rules = [(float('-inf'), 1000, a), (150, 185, b), (float('-inf'), 14, c)]

actual.sort()

for v in actual:
    for lo, hi, func in rules:
        if lo <= v <= hi:
            func(v)
```

**Output:**

```
a 12
c 12
a 175
b 175
a 500
```

Comment: I'm curious if that is what they were after - kinda looked that way to me.